# All emails to Gmail bounce as spam

Tags: spam, sendmail, microsoft-office-365, gmail

My organization failed to make changes in time to meet the new requirements that [came into effect on Feb 1st](https://blog.google/products/gmail/gmail-security-authentication-spam-protection/). So all emails to Gmail are rejected as spam.

We have since updated all our records so we are compliant with Google's requirements since a week ago. But our emails sent to Gmail are still blocked as spam. In Postmaster, we still have bad ratings on IP reputation and domain reputation is also on the way down. What else should be done to remove the spam classification of our domain?

Comment: **my organization failed to make changes in time so we met the new requirements that came to 1 feb. so all emails to gmail are rejected as spam. we have since updated all our records so we are compliant with Google's requirements since a week ago** - Your question assumes we know what you're referring to. Please specify what you are referring to.

Comment: Signalling sender authorization is only tangentially related to sender reputation. You should at the very least quote the specific message Google sent you (the SMTP status line and its continuations), to determine whether this is indeed in any way connected to that recent marketing campaign of Google. Or whether this is you not sending appropriate communications to consenting recipients.

Comment: I was unclear. from February 1, Yahoo and Google have had strict rules on how mail from the sender must be authenticated in order not to be classified as spam. It is important to have valid SPF, DKIM and DMARC records. If you are also a bulk sender, you must one-click the unsubscribe link, etc.

Comment: because we fail to enter these records in time, our domain ends up on some list where we are classified as spam senders, so all emails from us to Gmail recipients are automatically blocked. So we work on getting better IP and Domain reputation. the only thing that we see today that is not up to these new rules is that some outgoing mail fails the SPF test according to the DMARC report from google.

Comment: Have examples as below
source_ip count disposition dkim spf header_from domain2 result selector domain3 result4
2a01:111:f400:7e1a::702 1 none pass fail Mydomain.com Mydomain.com pass selector2 eur05-db8-obe.outbound.protection.outlook.com pass
2a01:111:f403:2608::700 1 none pass fail Mydomain.com Mydomain.com pass selector2 eur02-db5-obe.outbound.protection.outlook.com pass


Our SPF record is as follows
v=spf1 ip4:94.xxx ip4:94.xxx ip4:52.xxx
ip4:212.xxx ip4:151.xxx
include:spf.protection.outlook.com -all